# Find first distinct occurrence of character in a given string

Tags: c#

In C# how might I create a function that given a string, returns the first distinct character?

Example In: abcdabc
Example Out: d

Can I use `.Distinct()` to achieve this?

Comment: sample input and output?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-repeating"? As in, the next character is the same or that there is any other occurrence in the string?

Comment: What have you tried? What is expected output - char or char index? Provide some samples and describe problems you have

Comment: `returns the first occurrence of a non repeating character` isn't the first occurrence the only occurrence?

Comment: edited as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with LINQ as well. For example, this LINQ query will return e.

```
var str = "abcdeabcd";

var item = (from a in str group a by a 
 into grouped select new { character = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count() 
}).Where(t=>t.Count == 1)
.FirstOrDefault()?.character;

  Console.WriteLine(item);
```

or using LINQ with lambda expression with extension methods 
   (called method syntax),

```
var find = str.GroupBy(t => t)
.Select(y => new { character = y.Key, Count = y.Count() })
.Where(a => a.Count < 2).FirstOrDefault()?.character;

  Console.WriteLine(find);    

  Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I like this approach Amit

Comment: That second one is called method syntax.  Though technically you have a mix of method and query syntax in the first one anyway.

Comment: @juharr I meant lambda expression

Comment: @Amit That's still not what it's called.  If you use the Linq methods it's method syntax.  If you use the query language it's query syntax.

Comment: `Count == 1` might be clearer than `Count < 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "abcdabc";

var firstDistinct = input.Select((ch, index) => new {ch, index})
    .GroupBy(z => z.ch)
    .Where(z => z.Count() == 1)
    .OrderBy(z => z.Index())
    .Select(z => z.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Above finds the character that appears once (`Count() == 1`) and appears first (`OrderBy(z => z.Index())`).

***Technically** you don't need the `OrderBy` since the in-memory LINQ provider's `GroupBy` operator will keep the results in order by default. But that is an implementation detail, rather than a contractual obligation.* If you are happy to take advantage of this implementation detail (as all other answers here are) then consider:

```
var firstDistinct = input.GroupBy(z => z)
    .Where(z => z.Count() == 1)
    .Select(z => z.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
var str="abcdabcd";

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
   String ch = str[i].ToString();

   for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
   {
      if (ch == str[j].ToString())
      {
         break;
      }
      else
      {
         Response.Write("First Non repeating character : " + ch.ToString());
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why the call `ToString()` when you're comparing `char`s anyway?

Comment: Because `ch` is a `string`

Comment: @jmunoa7 But it doesnt have to be, you could just leave it char. This way you call `.ToString()` multiple times here: `str[i].ToString()` and here `str[j].ToString()` they were both chars but you made both strings...

Comment: This writes `b` to the response, which is not the expected result.